# Receiving a ValueError during max() operation

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to write code that will take an arbitrary amount of arguments (all integers) and return the result of the difference between the min and max of all the arguments. That is the code I've written up:

```
def checkio(*args):
    Max = max(args)
    Min = min(args)
    difference = Max - Min
    return difference
```

However I am receiving this error:

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

But if I throw a print statement in like this

```
def checkio(*args):
    Max = max(args)
    Min = min(args)
    difference = Max - Min
    print(difference)
    return difference
```

it does print the difference.

```
2
```

so, if the difference variable has the correct value, why cant it jump down one more line and return it?
Also, if max() is causing a problem, why does it make it down to difference in the first place?

The marking software is running this as its first test:

```
checkio(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get that error message is by passing an empty sequence to `max` and `min` functions, like this

```
>>> max(())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    max(())
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
>>> min(())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    min(())
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

In your case, if you invoke `checkio` without any parameters, `args` will be an empty tuple. That is why you are getting this error message.

Comment: You were definately correct.
The code was fixed with a simple 
    try/ except

Where I set except to:

    except ValueError:
       return 0

Answer (score 0):

The min or max function take a iterable object like list or string, more than one parameters is also ok.
so you can change the code like this:

```
def checkio(*args):

  Max = max(args)
  Min = min(args)

  difference = Max - Min

  return difference
print checkio(1,2,3,-1,9)
```

If you take a list as parameters, try this way:

```
def checkio(args):

  Max = max(args)
  Min = min(args)

  difference = Max - Min

  return difference
print checkio([1,2,3,-1,9])
```

star(*) in the parameters list means you can pass any parameter(s) to the function.But you must put the *parameter at last one like:

```
def sum_all(one, *args):

  return one +  sum(args)

print sum_all(1,1,2,3,34)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to be correct:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.1 (default, Nov 28 2014, 00:41:19) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def checkio(*args):
...     Max = max(args)
...     Min = min(args)
...     difference = Max - Min
...     return difference
... 
>>> checkio(2,3,4)
2
```

I only got the error, when running the function without any arguments:

```
>>> checkio()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in checkio
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
>>>
```